# Can I escape the `IO` in `catch`

Tags: haskell

Here's a type-puzzle for you. So we have

```
catch
  :: Exception e
  => IO a
  -> (e -> IO a)
  -> IO a
```

Is it possible for me to safely escape `IO` in the handler. I'm interested in a function with a signature similar to the following:

```
catchM
  :: Exception e
  => MonadIO io
  => MonadError e io
  => IO a
  -> (e -> io a)
  -> io a
```

Is this sensible or am I looking at this wrong?

Some additional context: My problem is that I'm using a library that throws exceptions in `IO`. I've wrapped some of these functions and lifted them into my own monad (using `liftIO`). I want to be able to catch some of the functions that this library can throw in the places where I call the lifted version that I've provided. Also, when I catch the exceptions, I would like to re-throw them inside my own error-handling framework.

Comment: Did you consider using `catchError` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-- Note that MonadError e io is unnecessary.
catchM :: (Exception e, MonadIO io) => IO a -> (e -> io a) -> io a
catchM m h = do
  r <- liftIO (try m)
  case r of
    Left e -> h e
    Right a -> pure a
```